# Updating Win10 using Setup for Windows 10 - Laptop shut down

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates, reinstall, setup

My laptop shuts down when the power cord is disconnected from it so I was reinstalling Windows while keeping my **files and applications** using [this](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209) link.

Though, my home electricity cut out **while** my laptop was running the setup (hence the laptop shuted down too). When I turned my laptop back on when the electricity came back, the SetUp showed that install couldn't happen, but now it is showing I have less space on my C drive (where Windows is installed) hence cannot run the setup again.

When I look at my C drive, these are the files that I see. The shaded files are like that constantly, and I **think** they have been added after the SetUp was stopped due to the electricity cut.:
[look of my C drive after failed update/reinstall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1YFv.png)

**Question:** Am I right that those files were added when trying to update/reinstall Windows 10? If yes, can I delete them and run the setup again?

Comment: Yes you can.  They are junk.  First try using the windows cleanup utility.. that often doesn't work and you might need to remove them by hand.